# Calculus Question about continuity

Tags: calculus

**Problem** 
$f^3(x)+2f(x)=x,$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Prove $x$ is continuous at $x_0=0$

$f(0)=0$ Obviously,and f is strictly increasing but every attempt of mine is foiled because the limit of f at zero is not mentioned to exist.

Comment: Welcome here! How did you show that $f$ is increasing? It may help to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, I did: Let $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} $with $x_1<x_2$ such that $ f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$ and ended up with a contradiction by building the first side and getting $x_1 \geq x_2$.

Comment: You need to assume $x_1<x_2$ in order to get a contradiction. That said, my idea was the same as @AnneBauval's answer.

Comment: Did you catch my answer before the edit? I think i assumed $x_1 <x_2$ or you’re talking about something different

Comment: No, I commented before seeing the edit

Answer (score 1):

From

$$f^3(x)+2f(x)=x$$ we get

$$|x|= |f(x)|(f(x)^2+2) \ge 2|f(x)|.$$

Your turn !

Comment: I tried taking the left and right limits of $x$ if that’s what you are referring to. I still can’t reach a conclusion though. I’m not sure what i’m allowed to do and what i’m not allowed to do in these situations.

Comment: From $|x|\ge 2|f(x)|$ we see that $|f(x)| \le |x|/2$ for all $x$. This gives (squeeze !): $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=0=f(0).$

Comment: Oh it does! Thank you, sorry for not seeing it initially.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\;y\mapsto y^3+2y$ is a continuous bijection.